# What does the bindinglistener in mvvmlight do

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

I have been doing some silverlight recently and was told that the bindinglistener in mvvmlight would be helpful.what does this class do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverlight 3, you cannot derive from DependencyObject, so you cannot add DependencyProperties to just any object. To work around that, you can use a BindingListener that will listen to property changes and then notify the bindings that something happened.

This limitation was lifted in Silverlight 4 so you don't need the binding listener if you upgrade to this version of Silverlight.

Makes sense?
Cheers,
Laurent